# Mysql Service Not Starting Because of too much read operation

Tags: mysql

```
$: sudo systemctl status mysql.service


● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (start) since Fri 2021-07-09 16:37:33 UTC; 45s ago
    Process: 1967655 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SU>
   Main PID: 1967663 (mysqld)
     Status: "Server startup in progress"
      Tasks: 21 (limit: 4619)
     Memory: 314.3M
     CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
             └─1967663 /usr/sbin/mysqld

Jul 09 16:37:33 server systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
```

Before getting the status mysql was read too much...(some 2000 rows in 20 minutes)....
I found that on this stage below ->

```
$: systemctl status mysql.service

● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset:>
     Active: activating (start) since Fri 2021-07-09 16:07:42 UTC; 973ms ago
    Process: 1966136 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (cod>
   Main PID: 1966144 (mysqld)
     Status: "Server startup in progress"
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 4619)
     Memory: 234.6M
     CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
             └─1966144 /usr/sbin/mysqld

Jul 09 16:07:42 server systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Jul 09 16:07:42 server systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Jul 09 16:07:43 server systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, co>
Jul 09 16:07:43 server systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'sig>
Jul 09 16:07:43 server systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
Jul 09 16:07:44 server systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, >
Jul 09 16:07:44 server systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Jul 09 16:07:44 server systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
```

because i have a very little knowledge about mysql,i was trying to restart it. At that time when I was trying to restart it...but it was giving this error below ->

```
$: sudo systemctl restart mysql

Job for mysql.service failed because a fatal signal was delivered to the control process.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

after giving journalctl it was giving this error

```
$: journalctl -xe

-- Automatic restarting of the unit mysql.service has been scheduled, as the result for
-- the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
Jul 09 16:45:24 server systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: A stop job for unit mysql.service has finished
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A stop job for unit mysql.service has finished.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 112583 and the job result is done.
Jul 09 16:45:24 server systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
-- Subject: A start job for unit mysql.service has begun execution
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit mysql.service has begun execution.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 112583.
Jul 09 16:45:36 server sshd[1968378]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname=>
Jul 09 16:45:38 server sshd[1968378]: Failed password for root from ip port 49068>
Jul 09 16:45:40 server sshd[1968378]: Received disconnect from ip port 49068:11: >
Jul 09 16:45:40 server sshd[1968378]: Disconnected from authenticating user root 184.69.65.>
Jul 09 16:45:44 server sudo[1967698]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
lines 1150-1172/1172 (END)
-- Automatic restarting of the unit mysql.service has been scheduled, as the result for
-- the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
Jul 09 16:45:24 server systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: A stop job for unit mysql.service has finished
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A stop job for unit mysql.service has finished.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 112583 and the job result is done.
Jul 09 16:45:24 server systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
-- Subject: A start job for unit mysql.service has begun execution
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit mysql.service has begun execution.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 112583.
Jul 09 16:45:36 server sshd[1968378]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0>
Jul 09 16:45:38 server sshd[1968378]: Failed password for root from ip port 49068 ssh2
Jul 09 16:45:40 server sshd[1968378]: Received disconnect from ip port 49068:11: Bye By>
Jul 09 16:45:40 server sshd[1968378]: Disconnected from authenticating user root ip por>
Jul 09 16:45:44 server sudo[1967698]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
lines 1150-1172/1172 (END)
```

Comment: Te last log shows: "Failed password for root from ip port 49068 ssh2" There should be enough questions, with answers, on how to reset the root password if you do not know the correct password....

Comment: 2000 rows in 20 minutes is not too much reading for a DB system, so that is not the problem for sure

Comment: the server ram is 1 giga...isn't that too less for reading 2000 rows in 20 minutes

Answer (score 0):

stopped every service... then my mysql server started...it felt like my server was low on ram...upgraded it ... then restarted all application services along with mysql service.... and any of it didn't go down...looks like mysql eats a lot of ram when you have 6 digit rows in your tables